# python-gi referencing wrong headers

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I'm trying to use gtk+ with python in Linux Mint 17. After trying the jhbuild method of building the gtk libraries for python, I tried to install from the Debian repositories and I tried to install with pip. Somewhere in the midst of that mess, I built two versions of gi for python. One of them sits in the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory and the other in the /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory. When trying to import gi.repository, I get the error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gi.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromUnicode
```

PyUnicodeUCS4_FromUnicode is defined in both the /usr/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h file and in the /usr/local/python2.7 directory. How can I get python to find when importing gi.repository?

Comment: Header files don't *define* symbols: you need to find the actual *library* file. BTW Mint is usually considered off-topic here.

Comment: Questions on Mint should be asked on [unix.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python was compiled with 2-byte representations of unicode characters instead of 4-byte representations. Fix by re-configuring with

```
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

See the following: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2.htm